# Cross-Compilation using kernel headers

Tags: kernel, compiling, kernel-modules, cross-compilation, compiler

I coded a kernel module for my RaspberryPi. However, I need to cross-compile the module on my Ubuntu Development machine. I already downloaded the correct kernel-headers on my RaspberryPi and pushed them to the Ubuntu machine.

Current Makefile (does not work):

```
obj-m += test.o
KDIR := /home/user/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.75-v7+/
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

Usage: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

Is it possible to cross-compile the kernel module by using the kernel headers only? Without compiling the whole kernel? How would the Makefile look like? What do I have to install?

Comment: What do you mean by "using the kernel headers only"?

Comment: Without compiling the whole Raspbian kernel on my Ubuntu machine